# Function calculates discount twice

Tags: javascript

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out why this function won't calculate correctly. If I run this function the discount (`totalPrice`) is applied twice, for example: `20*1.05 == 21`, but when the function runs and it gives me `22.05`.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function codeDiscount() {
        var totalCost = document.getElementById('total').value;
        var custCode = document.getElementById('coupon').value; 

        if (custCode == "ABCD" || custCode == "EFGH")
        {
            totalCost = document.getElementById('total').value; 
            var totalPrice = parseInt(totalCost) * 1.05;
            document.getElementById('total').value = totalPrice;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is calling this function?  also why are you setting totalCost twice to the same exact thing?

Comment: I don't see an error in the function itself, but I am guessing it's executed twice.... Try to step through it in a debugger

Comment: `parseInt('20') * 1.05` produces `21`,  what the value you got for `totalCost`?

Comment: @ryan a button is calling this function that takes the value of input id 'total' and multiplies it by a discount (1.05)

Comment: @TGH i tried the JS console debugger in firefox, but it returned nada

Comment: try putting an alert in after totalPrice to make sure it doesn't get fired twice

Comment: @mu interesting. i have some JS knowledge about that radix argument ( i know its important), but not sure how to use it

Comment: Always say `parseInt(x, 10)` unless you want a different base. What are you doing that http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/X5fpu/ isn't doing?

Comment: @xdazz, 20 is just an example. the real number is 159 -- when i run the function it should be 166.95, but it returns 174.3

Comment: @muistooshort the total input field is constantly being changed based on other variables. When they apply that discount code it should take the current value of the #total input and multiply by 1.05. the initial value of the #total field is generating based on a variable from another page

Comment: @muistooshort kudos! it was the radix argument, once i added it everything worked fine. much appreciated.

Comment: @muistooshort - `"Always say parseInt(x, 10)"`, or use `+x`, faster.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem isn't in this code block. Is there anything that would cause codeDiscount() to be called a second time?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is something wrong with ur code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function codeDiscount() {
        var totalCost = document.getElementById('total').value;
        var custCode = document.getElementById('coupon').value; 

        if (custCode == "ABCD" || custCode == "EFGH")
        {
            var totalPrice = parseInt(totalCost) * 1.05;
            document.getElementById('total').value = totalPrice;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also, please make sure that you don't call the same function twice. Otherwise, the result will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If your total field is being updated every time something changes, it's better to adopt this:

Store the total value in a separate variable:

```
var cartTotal = 0;
```

Then, whenever the sum of items changes, you update it:

```
// calculate sum of all products
cartTotal = 0;
for (var i in all_products) {
    cartTotal += all_procucts[i].price;
}
// calculate discount
codeDiscount();
```

To recalculate discount you use the `cartTotal` but you only update the field

```
var totalPrice = cartTotal;

if (custCode == 'ABCD') {
    totalPrice *= 1.05;
}

document.getElementById('total').value = totalPrice;
```